# Angle Bisector Proof Question

Tags: geometry

Please Help

A circle is drawn such that it intersects all three sides of $\triangle PQR$ as shown below. Prove that if $AB = CD = EF$, then the center of the circle is the incenter of $\triangle PQR$.

[image: Diagram]

Comment: Draw the perpendicular bisectors of $AB$, $CD$, and $EF$. They will meet at the same point (centre of circle).

Comment: Then draw a circle with that point as centre and those bisectors and sides. The circle will be tangent to all the three sides.

Comment: Which makes it the incentre by definition.

Answer (score 2):

If $O$ is the centre of the circle, then the triangles $\triangle ABO, \triangle CDO, \triangle EFO$ are congruent. Therefore these triangles have the same hight from $O$, let's call it $h$. In other words the distance between O and $PQ, QR, PR$ is the same (equals the hight $h$), but only the incenter has this property.

Answer (score 2):

HINT.-Equalities of chords $\overline {AB}=\overline {CD}=\overline {EF}$ imply equalities of arcs $\widehat{AB}=\widehat{CD}=\widehat{EF}$ so the perpendiculars to the middle of chords touch the middle of corresponding arcs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let us choose the special case when $$AB = CD= EF = 0 $$

Label the coincident points between the segments contained on the sides  as $L,M,N.$

Since two points  of intersection coincide, by definition the circle drawn is a tangent to  $AB $ at $L,$ and so for other two as well.

Normals of sides  at $L,M,N$ are concurrent at $I$ , the in-center which has to be the Centre of circle. QED